# Java primitive array List.contains does not work as expected

Tags: java, arrays, collections, primitive, primitive-types

Why when I use this code,

```
int[] array = new int[3];
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 1;
array[2] = 2;
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(1));
```

it outputs false. But when I use this code,

```
Integer[] array = new Integer[3];
array[0] = 0;
array[1] = 1;
array[2] = 2;
System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(1));
```

it outputs true?

Comment: It works as designed and advertised by the JLS. Just because it doesn't work as you *expected* doesn't mean its incorrect. Keep that in mind when chosing a question title; if you apply the simple logic: I'm learning a language that has been around for decades and something is not as *I* expect, is it more likely that the language is wrong or is it more likely I don't understand the language yet?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`Arrays.asList(int[])` will return a `List<int[]>`, which is why the output is `false`.

The reason for this behavior is hidden in the signature of the [`Arrays.asList()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Arrays.html#asList(T...)) method. It's

```
public static <T> List<T> asList(T... a)
```

The varargs, internally, is an *array of objects* (ot type `T`). However, `int[]` doesn't match this definition, which is why the `int[]` is considered as one single object.

Meanwhile, `Integer[]` **can** be considered as *an array of objects* of type `T`, because it comprises of objects (but not primitives).

Answer (score 3):

`Arrays.asList(array)` converts an `int[]` to a `List<int[]>` having a single element (the input array). Therefore that list doesn't contain 1.

On the other hand, `System.out.println(Arrays.asList(array).contains(array));` will print true for the first code snippet.

Comment: In other words, you do not get a `List` with integers, you get a `List` with one element, which is the integer array.